# Why can my binary operator not be applied to correctly typed operands?

Tags: swift, generics, binary-search-tree, associated-types

I'm building a binary search tree which will hold objects (I call them **Records**) whose type I don't know in advance. The tree will be ordered by a **Key** which is a part of the Record (type again not known). So I chose generics, the record conforming to a protocol which requires it to contain a Key and the key conforming to a protocol which requires it to have an operator which puts an order on two keys.

```
infix operator ⊰: ComparisonPrecedence

public enum Comparator {
   case matching
   case leftTree
   case rightTree
}

public protocol RecordProtocol {
   associatedtype Key: KeyProtocol
   var key: Key { get }
}

public protocol KeyProtocol {
   static func ⊰(lhs: Self,rhs: Self) -> Comparator
}

public enum Tree<R: RecordProtocol, K: KeyProtocol> {
   case empty
   indirect case node(_ record: R,_ left: Tree<R,K>,_ right: Tree<R,K>)
   public init() {
      self = .empty
   }
}

//This compiles perfectly fine
//Now I add a function to see if the tree contains a particular key

extension Tree {
   public func contains(_ key: K) -> Bool {
      switch self {
      case .empty:
         return false
      case let .node(record, left, right):
         switch key ⊰ record.key {
         case .matching: return true
         case .leftTree: return left.contains(key)
         case .rightTree: return right.contains(key)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The **switch** statement fails to compile with the message:

```
Binary operator '⊰' cannot be applied to operands of type 'K' and 'R.Key'
```

As far as I can see, both **key** and **record.key** are instances of **KeyProtocol** and should be available to the comparison operator **⊰**

Can anybody explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that `K` and `R.Key` are of the same type, since you defined your custom operator to accept two input arguments of the same type.

```
extension Tree where K == R.Key {
    public func contains(_ key: K) -> Bool {
        switch self {
        case .empty:
            return false
        case let .node(record, left, right):
            switch key ⊰ record.key {
            case .matching: return true
            case .leftTree: return left.contains(key)
            case .rightTree: return right.contains(key)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could modify `Tree` itself to ensure that `K` and `R.Key` are always the same type.

```
public enum Tree<R: RecordProtocol, K> where R.Key == K {
    case empty
    indirect case node(_ record: R,_ left: Tree<R,K>,_ right: Tree<R,K>)
    public init() {
        self = .empty
    }
}

extension Tree {
    public func contains(_ key: K) -> Bool {
        switch self {
        case .empty:
            return false
        case let .node(record, left, right):
            switch key ⊰ record.key {
            case .matching: return true
            case .leftTree: return left.contains(key)
            case .rightTree: return right.contains(key)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well **K** is of type **KeyProtocol** as set in the generic definition and R.Key is of type **Key** which is an associated type defined to be also **KeyProtocol**. I tried dropping the associated type and defining it directly as **KeyProtocol** but this is not allowed because: **Protocol 'KeyProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements**

Comment: @Tchelyzt you still need to guarantee that the two types are equal. You could also modify `Tree` to ensure that's the case, check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks David, looks like that works although I don't understand why. I'm guessing that key and record.key are both variables that comply with Keyprotocol but not necessarily the same types?

Comment: @Tchelyzt neither of them are variables, they are generic types with type constraints. Even though they are both of type `Key`, you need to ensure that they are both of the same `Key` type, which your existing type constraints didn't ensure.